# Why can't my include function get the global variable value?

Tags: php

I have a func.inc file as below

```
// STATUS_VALLUE
$status_failure = 0;
$status_success = 1;

function resultResultJson($status) {
    echo $status;
    echo $status_success;
}
```

And my function.php as below

```
<?php 
    include("./includes/func.inc");
    resultResultJson($status_success);
?>
```

I'm expected result `11`. But I got `10`. Why is the function `resultResultJson` not getting the right `$status_success` result?

**Updated**

The https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/3286489 provides explanation on the variable scope, which explains why, but doesn't give a resolution. The below answer by @Niyoko Yuliawan helps.

Comment: Change `func.inc` to `func.inc.php` and see what happens

Comment: Add `<?php` to the start of the inc file

Comment: And then there is [SCOPE, Scope, scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) `$status_success;` is not visible inside the function

Comment: shall I, oh i already did

Comment: The pointed duplicate reference does explain about scope, but doesn't give the resolution to how to solve this. The below answer helps indeed.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, the references to http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php helps. As a C and Java developer, this is puzzling that something declared globally are not taken into consideration in an inner function. Hence I ask this question puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `$status_success` variable as global variable.

```
function x($status){
    global $status_success;
    echo $status;
    echo $status_success;
}
```

Comment: Cool. That helps much! I upvote your answer and tick it, as it helps. I think my question is valid, as I can't really find a solution else where. Even the marked duplicate answer didn't tell me to put global. If you agree with me, perhaps you could help upvote my question back, as I don't think it deserved a negative vote. Thanks!

Comment: @Elye I upvoted your question, but it won't negate -2 downvotes as I can only upvote once.

Comment: Thanks @Niyoko Yuliawan. That's good enough. I think stackoverflow should enforce whoever down vote, should at least put a comment of reason why they down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the file name `func.inc` into `func.inc.php` so that PHP can parse that code. Also, don't forget to add `<?php` tags at the start to claiming that PHP script is going to start.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not the case.